# Input a date and give a date in the future

Tags: php

I am letting a user input a date. How should I return a date from their input and add 3 years to it? I tried to use `mktime` and `date` but it did not work out very well.

```
$input_date = 2010-03-28
```

My solution currently is just basic math for a given date 3 years ahead.

```
$input_date = $input_date + 3000;
```

Let's say I would want to give a date 4 years and 4 months 10 days

```
$future_date1 _datum = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-2, date("d"),   date("Y")+3);
$future_date2 = mktime(0, 0, 0,     date("m"), date("d"),   date("Y")+3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtotime('+ 3 years')` or `DateInterval` for an object oriented approach.

Comment: This does not demonstrate how to change user provided dates

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime()` offers multiple ways to do this. It's the way PHP recommends doing date math.

You can use [`DateTime::modify()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

```
$date = new DateTime($input_date);
$date->modify('+3 months');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

// one-liner
echo (new DateTime($input_date))->modify('+3 months')->format('Y-m-d');
```

or with [`DateInterval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

```
$date = new DateTime($input_date);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P3M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

// one-liner
echo (new DateTime($input_date))->add(new DateInterval('P3M'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: would $date = DateTime(2014-02-06);
new $date= modify('+3 months'); work?

Comment: That would work if you include the `+` sign in your modify method call. [See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zYDbIz).

Answer (score 1):

Use the strtotime function:

```
$input_date = '2010-03-28';
$future_date = strtotime("+3 years", strtotime($input_date);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Returns a timestamp, if you want to return YYYY-mm-dd: `$future_date = date("Y-m-d", $future_date);`